# Getting users input then outputting it

Tags: python, input, operating-system

Im trying to make an easy way of installing powercord themes but im not sure how i could get the users input then output it in a os.system command, this is what i have now

````py
import os
import colorama
import time

input("Hi please insert a github powercord theme link: ")

themelink = ""

print("installing powercord theme...")

os.system("cd C:/Users/kai78/powercord/src/Powercord/themes && git clone {}".format(themelink))```
````

Answer (score 2):

You have to save your input when you get it.

```
some_input = input('Type something: ')
```

Comment: it gives me the same error fatal: repository '{coolinput}' does not exist

Comment: Try checking your path, maybe you installed it in a different directory, but on their discord it shows: cd powercord/src/Powercord/themes && git clone <link>